# Is Rails 3 ready for use in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm looking to get a snapshot of Rails 3 at this point in time. We're about to start a new long term project, and I'm wondering if R3 is ready for real use. Or, if there are still a lot of bumps to be worked out. E.g. I saw questions about its compatibility with Passenger. (?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rails 3 is very much ready for production use. It's in use on big sites like [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/) (you can read about their long path to Rails 3 here: http://blog.shopify.com/2010/11/16/our-upgrade-to-rails-3).

I've recently upgraded my own Rails 2.3.x app to Rails 3, and it runs fine on Passenger. I didn't encounter any compatibility problems with Passenger 3 and the [site](http://www.wego.com/) has been running on Rails 3 + Passenger for about a month now with no problems.

Since you're starting a new project, I'd **strongly recommend** you start on Rails 3 because frankly the upgrade to Rails 3 can be quite painful like Shopify's story.

Comment: We upgraded our project, it was awfully painful.

Answer (score 3):

Yes Rails 3 is ready for production. Many sites are already using it in production. The compatibility issue is because Rails 3 is using Rack, Passenger will treat Rails 3 apps as Rack apps when it sees config.ru in the application root directory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any sites in particular you know about? Also, your note about Passenger: does that mean it will or won't work?

Comment: I don't know many big websites that are using it. But http://answers.37signals.com/ is using Rails 3.  It will still work but it treats it as Rack app.

Answer (score 0):

What is your current rails experience?

- If you have prior rails experience and you want to get something out quickly, I'd go with what you know, so Rails 2, and only port afterwards.
- If just starting out and no previous experience, I'd go for Rails 3. You would be better off learning the new thing immediately. There's [a great rails tutorial](http://railstutorial.org/) out there.

I'm quite confident that Rails 3 is in good shape, though there's bound to be some kinks left and there is new stuff to learn which might slow you down a bit at first.